# Django model db_table inheritance/injection

Tags: django, django-models, django-inheritance

I'm doing an integration between Django and AWS Redshift for reporting purposes. So far it feels like django isn't doing well with it. One of the problems I encountered is that I have to set an alternative type id for each model, rather than the AutoField type because it's not supported in redshift.
so far so good, but I thought If I'm already doing a super class for all the models that I'm going to use I will change the table names on the way, I don't like the default names that django gives for it's models in the db (app_name__model_name). I managed to do it for every sub model (see below). but I would like to declare it dynamically in BaseModel in a way that each sub model will receive it's own table name according to it's class name.

```
class BaseModel(Model):
    id = CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=36)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RedshiftBaseModel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.id = str(uuid4())


class SubModel1(BaseModel):
    class Meta(BaseMode.Meta):
        db_table = 'SubModel1'

    field1 = CharField(max_length=64, primary_key=True)


class SubModel2(BaseModel):
    class Meta(BaseMode.Meta):
        db_table = 'SubModel2'

    field2 = CharField(max_length=64, primary_key=True)
```

Is such thing even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you *certainly* do not want to set `self.id` in the `__init__` method; that will be called every time an item is instantiated, even when it is being loaded from the database, in which case the db ID will be overridden. Much better is to make it a default value:

```
id = CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=36, default=uuid4)
```

(although also note that Django 1.8 introduced a UUIDField, so you could just use that).

To answer your main question, though, it is possible - but only through some very complex overriding of the model metaclass (not to be confused with the model's Meta class...). It would almost certainly be more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: You're right about the id, thanks. Can you refer me to any resource regarding the override of the metaclass?